# What is the sum of a and b, minus c?

Tags: swift

When I'm doing the Swift Apprentice challenges, I meet some problems.

The challenge in chapter 2 :

What is the sum of a and b, minus c?

```
let a = 4
let b: Int32 = 100
let c: UInt8 = 12
```

It seems that we cannot add or minus when the variables are mixed types.

So what's the result of this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift disallows mathematical operations between different numeric types. Writing:

```
let result = a + b - c // error
```

...is an error. Unless you have specific requirements, like all the operands are non-negative, the rule of thumb is to convert everything to the widest data type, in this case `Int`:

```
let result = a + Int(b) - Int(c) // 92
```

Comment: Ah, but maybe it's a tricky question. Error is the result of that expression.

Answer (score 1):

For a complete answer I would say

"Swift does not allow you to do math with different mathematical types. The expression a+b-c will throw an error, so we need to cast all the values to the same type:

```
let result = a+Int(b)-Int(c)
```

"

(As Code Different says in their answer, you should "promote" values to the widest/richest type {e.g. from smaller integer types to larger, from unsigned to signed, or from integer to floating point if any of the values are floating point.})